# Simple JavaScript Chrome Extension - Opening a URL - modified from Input Text

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the code below to make a simple chrome extension, to have input text, and a button, and upon a button click, I want to pull up a specific URL. I'm having trouble writing the code.  I'm fairly new to JavaScript.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Title Name</title>
      <style>
  body {
    min-width: 357px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
  }
</style>

 </head>
 <body>
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="67" id="lolz" />
    <button type="button" id="the_button">LookUp Site ID</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### popup.js - Updated

```
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
 document.getElementById('the_button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
   function myFunction() { 
var siteid = document.getElementById('lolz').value 
  //window.location = "https://www.websiteimusing.com/siteid" + siteid;
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.websiteimusing.com/siteid" + siteid}); 
  }
 }
```

}

### Manifest.json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "ID URL opener",
   "description": "Enter ID and it will pull up the correct URL",
   "version": "1.0",

   "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
 "permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

### Current Error - Updated

It is not populating a error, just never actually loading the URL upon button click, any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Read the description of the [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked)` event. Hint 2: Know [where](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup) to read error messages.

Comment: The `browserAction.onClicked` listener cannot be used while the browser action has a popup assigned.

Comment: @apsillers So is what im trying to do not going to work. Take a look at my updated code

Comment: The button is in popup.html, so you need to listen to the button's onclick event, instead of `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`. Assign an id to the button (say id="open"), and add the event listener with `document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', function() { /* Your code to open a new tab */});`. Also remember to include the JavaScript in the HTML.

Comment: @方觉 I've updated my code, please take a 2nd look if you dont mind

Comment: `function myFunction() {
     var siteid = document.getElementById('lolz').value
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://www.websiteimusing.com/siteid/" + siteid});
}` and add `<script src="popup.js"></script>` after `</button>`.

Comment: @方觉 yeah its still not working, No error message just never actually opens the URL

Comment: @JaisonBrooks where do you want to pull the url?.. in the popup? or on the page?... to see the errors... go to chrome://extensions and under your plugin open the generated popup.html check the console there

Comment: @whizzzkid I would like to display the popup, inside the popup is the input text and the button, the user will input text, then click the button, this will launch a new tab/window (whichever) with a modified URL (url + inputText)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay, it's actually very simple to implement. <strike>you just need to add to this a background.js file.</strike>

Here is the flow of the extension:

1. the popup.js receives the input text
2. the popup.js raises <strike>an event request</strike> a new tab request
3. <strike>the background.js listens to the event and gets data from the request</strike>
4. <strike>the background.js then creates a new tab with the src as url+input</strike>

you're done, <strike>will you be willing for me to write this code?</strike>

---

**EDIT: The Code**

---

The best part is, now you will not need to pass messages to background.js as per latest chrome extension docs the tab permission can be accessed from popups. The following code will take an input string in popup and will send the user in a new tab where the input string is searched on google. Most of the code is self explanatory, **Lemme know if you're not able to work it out, i will send you the crx + source**

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name"          : "Simple Search",
    "version"       : "0.1",
    "manifest_version"  : 2,
    "description"       : "Simple Search Plugin",
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon_48.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Simple Search",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
    "permissions"       :
        [
            "tabs"
        ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
            body{
                font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="width:300px;">
    <center>
      <h1>Simple Search</h1>
      <input type="text" id="q"></input>
      <input type="button" id="s" value="search">
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
$(function() {
  $('#s').click(function() {
     var url  = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + $('#q').val();
     chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
  });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded');
```

Comment: IF you want to write it that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Im just a little unsure on the background.js part

Comment: @JaisonBrooks please check and confirm!