# JavaScript not allowing input before running

Tags: javascript, html, url

Im having issues with this javascript running prior to the user input, can someone help me fix this.

im just trying to make a little html page with a textbox and a button, that then clicked opens a new windows with a modified URL.

```
<input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="lolz" />
<button type="button" id="the_button">Count</button>

document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', myFunction());
function myFunction() {
  var button = document.getElementById("the_button");
  var siteid = document.getElementById('lolz').value
  button.onclick = count();

  function count() {
    window.location = "http://www.websiteimusing.com/" + siteid;
  }
 }
```

You can check the code out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ck5Yz/17/)
The Actually generate output from that website's code is [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ck5Yz/18/show/light/)

### Updated Code

```
document.getElementById('the_button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
 function myFunction() {
   var button = document.getElementById("the_button");
   var siteid = document.getElementById('lolz').value
    button.onclick = count();

 function count() {
     window.location = "http://www.websiteimusing.com/" + siteid;
   }
  }
```

Comment: where is Id `#open` used here? you are not using it anywhere in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no element with id `open` in your code, so you're trying to add an event listener to null. The console will tell you the same:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null`

Also make sure to remove the parens from your event listener function, as the other posters have stated.

Comment: What else is going on with it? If I had to guess, it would probably be that `siteid` is not defined either, nor is it passed into the `count()` function, so it's looking for a variable called `siteid` outside of the function's scope.

Comment: Well im also trying to take this code i've updated above that is working in the example link i've provided to a google chrome extention. See question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661933/simple-javascript-chrome-extension-opening-a-url-modified-from-input-text?noredirect=1#comment25733467_17661933

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

When you put `()` after a function name, it means to call the function at that time.

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', myFunction());
```

you are calling the function by adding the `()`

change that to:

```
document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```